# Как увеличить текст кода или размер окна в Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Пробовал использовать стандартное  сочетание ctrl + s, но оно не помогает. Может есть другие горячие клавиши?

Answer (score 9):

Так же в настройках (`File->Settings`) можно включить изменение масштаба, используя Ctrl и колёсико мыши:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вернуть в изначальное положение?

Answer (score 2):

Можно самому задать удобное сочетание: Settings -> Keymap -> находим все настройки для шрифта по ключевому слову 'font' -> щелкаем правой кнопкой на нужной -> выбираем 'Add Keybord Shortcut' -> задаем удобное сочетание

Answer (score 1):

```
1. File --> Settings...
2. In left side expand Editor --> Font
3. Change Size value.
4. Press "Apply" and "OK"
```